# Maya API to C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, api, maya

I was reading about the Maya API to C++ and didn't quite understand the idea.

Upon implementing the API, Can I create an environment, or a GUI in 3D world in Visual Studio?

This question is related to my previous one about the Maya API.
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056606/does-maya-mel-have-a-good-api-to-a-ide)

If someone could give me a good place to begin, it would be great.

Thanks,
Oded.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create 3D environment outside the Maya,
as well as you can do anything inside Maya with the API.

I recommend that you start with Maya python API instead of c++ it's way easier, and takes less development time.

you may read the "Complete Maya Programming" book, its example written in c++, but if you know some python you can write them in python.

Comment: So basically the api lets me do everything in Maya, but from Visual Studio in C++ ?

Comment: with maya you cant do any development FOR outside maya..
but if youre wondering  whether you can develop plugins using VS, sure you can..
btw do you work as TD or something, what do you do on maya?

Comment: I'm a student getting close to my final project of BSc degree, and I thought about using my knowledge of Maya (I've made short animation movies in the past) in my Project.

Answer (score 2):

Maya API allows you to extend Maya, and you can choose to use either c++ or python (the python just wraps same API, more or less). Now the extension framework is meant for you to implement your own nodes, importers/exporters and motion capture devices, mostly. The GUI layer is reserved to scripting components and QT neither which are exactly Maya APIS domain, tough it gives you hooks to do with with the script environment or QT.

As for the exact question can you create a GUI yes you can get a handle to the QT framework, but as i previously said its not the realm of the API per see. And as for the environment yes you could do that its just not the sort of thing you'd do as your first project. You do almost anything you like, inside or even a connection outside of Maya however from a practical standpoint you'd still have to quite intimately know Maya before starting to do so. The API doesn't exactly allow you to do anything you like it has certain no bounds limitations and its not a good idea to fight Mayas run time environment.

If on the other hand you want to control things within Maya externally then make a node or a motion capture server, that's what they are meant for.

Personally i find the complete Maya programming book a bit misleading on all levels but yes you could use it as basis. Just not terribly fruitful for any of the tasks you ask for.